# How do I get a string out of a boost shared memory vector w/o triggering an allocation in shared memory from the constructor of the retrieved string?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-memory

given these types (from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html), more or less):

```
typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager SegmentManager;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, SegmentManager> CharAllocator;

typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> ShmString;

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<ShmString, SegmentManager> StringAllocator;

typedef boost::interprocess::vector<ShmString, StringAllocator> ShmStringVector;
```

Whenever I retrieve a ShmString from the `ShmStringVector`, the free size of my shared memory segment goes down.

What I think is happening is whenever `ShmString` is constructed, even as a stack variable, it allocates space inside the shared memory segment.

When that `ShmString` goes out of scope, the memory gets returned. But if I'm close to capacity on my segment, I don't want accesses risking causing an overrun on the shared memory segment.

How can I get the string out without triggering another allocation?

In the example below, I tried

```
//shared mem segment previously created with 1,000,000 bytes allocated
managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "somename");
CharAllocator charAllocator(segment.get_segment_manager());
ShmStringVector *vec = segment.find<ShmStringVector>("somevectorname").first;

vec->push_back(" ... big string ..."  );       // I can push a const char*
size_t sizeAfterInsertion = segment.get_free_memory();

ShmString   res1 = vec->at(0);  //works, but steals memory from shared memory, at least temporarily !
const char* res2 = vec->at(0);  //compiler error
std::string res3 = vec->at(0);  //compiler error 
size_t sizeAfterGet = segment2.get_free_memory();
size_t diff = sizeAfterInsertion - sizeAfterGet;
```

I proved to myself memory was being taken by declaring `ShmString`...

```
std::string size 170,     
before ins:    999232, after ins: 998976, shared memory taken by ins: 256 
                       after get: 998768, shared memory taken by get: 208
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Wug mentions, you can use a reference.

#### Converting/assigning between string types:

If you really want a copy, outside the shared memory, copy to a regular (or other-allocator) string:

```
std::string copied(vec2->at(0).begin(), vec2->at(0).end());
```

Of course, the same works vice versa:

```
vec2[0].assign(copied.begin(), copied.end());
// Or
vec2->emplace_back({copied.begin(), copied.end()});
```

etc.

#### Using streams directly on shared memory

Note also that there is [streaming support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html) for Boost Interprocess:

```
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
   IntAllocator;
typedef allocator<char, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
   CharAllocator;
typedef vector<int, IntAllocator>   MyVector;
typedef basic_string
   <char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator>   MyString;
typedef basic_vectorstream<MyString>               MyStringStream;
```

Now you can use `MyVectorStream` to read/write to the shared memory string. It's akin to `std::stringstream` but without having to copy the data into the stream first.

E.g write some data to a vector:

```
   //Create the stream. To create the internal shared memory
   //basic_string we need to pass the shared memory allocator as
   //a constructor argument
   MyStringStream mystringstream(CharAllocator(segment.get_segment_manager()));

   //Reserve the internal string
   mystringstream.reserve(100*5);

   //Write all vector elements as text in the internal string
   //Data will be directly written in shared memory, because
   //internal string's allocator is a shared memory allocator
   for(std::size_t i = 0, max = myvector->size(); i < max; ++i){
      mystringstream << (*myvector)[i] << std::endl;
   }
```

And read it back to copy it directly into another shared memory string:

```
  //Auxiliary vector to compare original data
   MyVector *myvector2 =
      segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector2")
      (IntAllocator(segment.get_segment_manager()));

   //Avoid reallocations
   myvector2->reserve(100);

   //Extract all values from the internal
   //string directly to a shared memory vector.
   std::istream_iterator<int> it(mystringstream), itend;
   std::copy(it, itend, std::back_inserter(*myvector2));

   //Compare vectors
   assert(std::equal(myvector->begin(), myvector->end(), myvector2->begin()));
```

This taken from the documentation sample and you can see it **[<strike>Live</strike> On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f1f450ac11edd4a**

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.  When pushing things into the vector, what do you suggest?  I also notice simply declaring a ShmString on the stack takes shared memory, the vec->push_back(str); takes even more by tripping the copy-constructor.  Would boost::move be appropriate?

Comment: You can use emplace (demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/780489991a345ca6)**), see also e.g. [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280041/how-to-i-create-a-boost-interprocess-vector-of-interprocess-containers/26281947#26281947). Of course, this could have been posted as a separate question

Answer (score 2):

Use a reference.

```
ShmString &res1 = vec2->at(0);
```

Remember that this isn't actually making a copy of the string, but referring to the original string.  This will be perfectly sufficient for just reading its contents (in which you should declare `res1` to be `const` as well).